# How I specify a covariate in Anova model (r)

Tags: r, anova

I have the following model:

```
model = aov(y ~ treatment + Age, data = dt)
```

How I determine `Age` as a covariate (covariable) in r? Is there a code or R only knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply including another variable in your model statement, you've included it as a covariate in your model.  So for example, a general model would look like this:

```
model = model_type(dependent_variable ~ independent_variable + covariate, data = dataset_name),
```

In the example you provided, you specified an ANOVA `model_type` (`aov`) by including `Age` on the right side of the tilde (`~`).  By doing that, you have included it as a covariate when you've included some other variable as your independent variable of interest (in your example, treatment).

Examples are found all over the internet and throughout the r documentation.  Try for example `help(aov).`

Comment: So, it's related of the variable format too. The format of covariate must be numeric.

Comment: @CuriousG., Not necessarily.  It can also be a factor.

Comment: I don't think so. I think that the trick is the format. Try to do an Anova using different formats, the Anova table will be totally different.

Comment: The covariate can be in levels as a factor, but the format must be numeric.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "the trick."  What trick?  The trick for doing what?   You simply include an additional variable, numeric or factor on the right side of the `~` to include it as a covariate.  

I've done hundreds, if not thousands of ANOVA's in R before.  Of course you will get totally different ANOVA tables if you use different inputs.  

I have no idea what you mean by the format must be numeric.  Covariates can be numeric or factors.

Comment: But covariate and Factors (treatments) are different things and are analyzed in different ways in ANOVA. And so, for R understand a covariate like as such, and not a factor (treatment), the format must be numeric in dataset. I did this and the results are different.

Comment: While the treatment needs to be in the factor format.

Comment: OK.  Now I think I understand what's going on!  Ii think you are using the word "covariate" slightly different that I was using it, and you are mis-using the word "format" as it does not mean what you think it means in R.  I think this article will help you understand:  https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/confusing-statistical-terms-5-covariate/

I think what you are trying to say is that a covariate term should in ANOVA/ANCOVA should be continuous.  If that's the case, then, yes, technically speaking, it should be continuous to be called a "covariate."  In reality, a covariate can be either.

Comment: Ohh I'm so sorry, I'm not a native in English. And thanks for your patience and attention. I appreciate your support. =D

Comment: No problem at all!  I'm just glad I could finally figure out where the disconnect was.  That last comment of your cracked the case (as we say in English)!  Anyway, I think that link will provide you with some clarification.